Package 'mariadb-server' has no installation candidate
Im currently trying to install mariadb after deleting it with sudo apt-get purge mariadb-server-core because it wasnt working, but now I get the error: Unable to locate package mariadb or Package 'mariadb-server' has no installation candidate.
Does anyone know how I can fix this?
Thank you!
EDIT:
I just ran mariadb --version and I got this:mariadb from 11.4.2-MariaDB, client 15.2 for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper.
I dont know why tho, I thought it removed it...
But I still get an error when running mariadb:ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Have you run sudo apt update lately?  Run that first.

@ThomasWard yea, just tried it again it still has the same error

Questions about Debian are off topic at Ask Ubuntu.
